# Longest word in a given string in C

Tags: c, string

The input given is a string (space separated) and the aim is to find the longest string. I have the following code and it crashes for some reason.

The input format is :
Good Morning

Expected Output:
Morning

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[1001], temp[1001];
    int maxLen= INT_MIN;
    while(scanf("%s", str)==1)
    {
        //printf("%s\n", str);
        if(strlen(str)>maxLen)
        {
            strcpy(temp, str);
            maxLen = strlen(str);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", temp);
}
```

I am not able to figure out why this is crashing...! Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Thanks everyone for helping! I have posted the final working answer below!

Comment: Try `unsigned long maxlen = 0;` (or `size_t maxlen = 0;`), otherwise, in the comparison, `maxlen` is converted to some unsigned type where `INT_MIN`has a very large positive value... and you'll be printing random garbage values in `temp`.

Comment: With proper options, a decent compiler will warn you about comparison between unsigned and signed values. Always **turn on and mind the warnings** (`gcc ... -Wsign-compare ...`, or more inclusive `gcc ... -Wextra ...`, unfortunately nor part of `gcc ... -Wall ...`)

Comment: The question is confusing.  You say it crashes, but also that it provides the output "Morning" when given input "Good Morning".  Does it crash, or does it give the correct output?  Does it give the output and then crash?  Does it work on that particular input but crash on other input?  Asking clear question is the key to getting good answers.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It is actually the expected output! I have edited the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted by @mch, strlen(str) returns an unsigned integer. So, I typecasted it to integer. And now it works fine!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[1001], temp[1001];
    int maxLen= INT_MIN;
    while(scanf("%s", str)==1)
    {
        //printf("%s\n", str);
        if((int)strlen(str)>maxLen)
        {
            strcpy(temp, str);
            maxLen = strlen(str);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line `if(strlen(str)>maxLen)`:

`strlen(str)` returns a `size_t`, an unsigned integer.
When you compare an `int` and a `size_t`, the `int` gets converted to `size_t`, resulting in a very big number.

So the comparison is always false.

Then you try to print the uninitialized buffer `temp`.

Change `int maxLen= INT_MIN;` to `size_t maxLen = 0;`

Comment: I made the changes, but now it is taking inputs infinitely.

Comment: You need to tell to your program you won't input anything more. You can do that by hitting ctrl-d